# Copy from vim to python console in tmux

Tags: python-3.x, vim, console, tmux

I have installed tmux.

```
tmux -V
tmux 2.3
```

Set my configure file.

```
cat  ~/.tmux.conf
set -g mouse on
```

Enter tmux and  open a two vertical windows in it,open python3 console in the left,open vim in the right.

[image]

Now move my cursor at the beginning of the first line in the right with mouse.
Enter into normal mode and input `2yy+`, to copy two lines in my `+` register.
Move cursor at the left `python3 console` window ,how can i paste content in `+` register into the python console?
@Kent,do as you say:
1.Move cursor at the beginning of first line,and type `"+2Y`
2.Move cursor to the left window,and middle-click mouse,nothing happen.
3.press `ctrl+b` then press `]` key.

[image]

Comment: [vim-tmux-clipboard](https://github.com/roxma/vim-tmux-clipboard) plugin might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first your vim should be compiled with `+clipboard` see `vim --version | grep 'clipboard'`

To copy ( or delete ) in any vim register you can use the following syntex

- `"<register name><oprator><motion>` (see `:h registers` )e.g.

  1. `"ayy`(copy current line in register `a`) or
  2. `"bdd`(delete current line in register `b`) or
  3. `"*ce`(delete to the end of the current work and place content in register `*` using `c` will also put you in insert mode
- to copy whole line you can use `yy`
- and system clipboard is mapped to either `+` or `*` ( depending on the os )

so to copy the whole line into system clipboard you can use

- `"*yy` or `"+yy` (depending on the os)

or to copy 2 lines

- `"*2yy` or `"+2yy` ( to copy current and the line after current line )

once the content is copied in the system clipboard you can **paste in tmux using ( `command + v` or `ctrl + shift + v` )**

or to map system clipboard with tmux paste buffer see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67673/copy-paste-text-selections-between-tmux-and-the-clipboard#72340

Answer (score 1):

`2yy+` does **NOT** copy two lines into `+` reg, instead, it yanks two lines to `"` reg, then moves the cursor to first non-blank char in next line

You can on the vim side do: `"*2Y` then do a mouse middle-click on the python console.

- or simply select the lines you want to copy in vim by mouse, then middle click in python console

Comment: I can press middle-clic on gedit to paste lines in it ,don't know why can't paste it in the left window.

Comment: Should i write some configuration in ~/.tmux.conf ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite like with the accepted solution that it depends on a graphical environment for the clipboard since this does not work when `vim` can not access the clipboard, which is almost always the case for `ssh` connections.
So I cam up with another solution:

Instead of using the external clipboard `vim` can pass the text directly into `tmux`' paste buffer by piping it into

```sh
tmux load-buffer -
```

After that you can paste the content of the buffer with `prefix + ]` into the active `tmux` pane.

There are various ways to pass the text from `vim` to `tmux`:

```
# to write the current line into the tmux buffer:
:.w !tmux load-buffer -

# to write all *lines* within the visual selection into the tmux buffer:
:'<,'>w !tmux load-buffer -

# to pipe the content of a register (e.g. from a previous selection) into the buffer:
# @" being the unnamed register, @0 - @9 the numbered registers, and so on
:call system('tmux load-buffer -', @")
```

Using `tmux paste-buffer` you can even trigger the pasting into the correct pane at the same time:

```
# assuming the python pane is at :0.0
:call system('tmux load-buffer -; tmux paste-buffer -t :0.0', @")
```

You can now also easily map the last line to a key to send the visually selected text to the `python` pane.